# rsync to copy folders local and remote

Tags: windows-7, rsync

I'm trying to copy a directory with files and folders to another directory, first locally to test, and then to a remote server. The tool that I must use is `rsync`, but after a lot of testing and reading the docs I can't make it work under `Windows 7`.

For example, when I try

`rsync -av D:\source\ D:\dest\`

I get the error `The source and destination cannot both be remote.`

When I try `rysnc -av \source\ D:\dest\`, I get `Error: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)`

Do you know how can I get it to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Which rsync client are you using?

Comment: rsync  version 3.0.4  protocol version 30

Comment: Is that with cygwin, SFU, Grsync? I'm guessing the command is treating D:\ as a directory on remote server D

Comment: it's with cygwin, though I don't know how it works, or how to check if it works, D:\ is a local drive, just like C:\, i'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 6):

Cygwin paths are different, to make them Unix-like.  Use

```
rsync -av /cygdrive/d/source/ /cygdrive/d/dest/
```

D: is interpreted as a remote server called D

Comment: Thank you very very much, It works, I had no clue that it needed '/cygdrive/', Best regards, Andrei

Comment: By the way, and if the destination target is a remote Win server, that I access it with \\server\dest_folder\ in win Explorer, how should I write it in cygwin?

Comment: It depends what ssh server is on the remote machine but it will be server: then the path.  The easiest way is probably to map \\server\dest_folder to a network drive e.g. R then you can just use a local rsync to /cygdrive/r/

Comment: Is there a good way to do this when the pathnames have spaces involved? I try `"/cygdrive/d/source with spaces/"`, in quotes due to the spaces in the pathname, but I get an error message that the source is a remote directory (it's not).

Comment: I haven't got cygwin installed anymore, but you could try `/cygdrive/d/"source with spaces"/` or `/cygdrive/d/source\ with\ spaces/`

Answer (score 0):

Gravedigger coming back to dig this up -

On my windows 8.1 machine it was running everything fine but5 on my Windows 7 machine I was having this same issue.  Fixed it by editing vagrant's source -

For me it was here - C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.6.3\plugins\synced_folders\rsync\helper.rb

And I added cygdrive as a prefix and everything is going well -

```
    if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
      # rsync for Windows expects cygwin style paths, always.
      # Editing source is never fun, but it works : /
      hostpath = "/cygdrive" + Vagrant::Util::Platform.cygwin_path(hostpath)
    end
```